# Entity Framework migration falsly detected as pending

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I merged 2 migrations that were previously applied on the database into one

Now the dbContext correctly detects, that the model is compatible using `context.Database.CompatibleWithModel`

Problem starts after a new migration was added. The model is now not compatible, so the migrator will apply pending migrations. The problem is, that the merged migration is also detected as pending.

Any ideas, what could be the problem here?

Comment: How did you "merge" the migrations? CompatibleWithModel compares the schema with the stored model. Application of migrations is a different process.

Comment: @SteveGreene in the package manager console I got to the state before the 2 partial migrations, then removed them from my project and scaffolded a new one

Comment: Makes sense. It is a new migration so EF is going to try to apply it because there is no record in __MigrationHistory. If those changes have already been applied to the database, you will need to comment out the Up() code and do an `update-database` so the new model is reflected in the the latest migration. [Here](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/) is another way to do it.

Comment: @SteveGreene I need to apply this in production environment

Answer (score 0):

OK, not the cleanest solution, but this is the least painful path I found

Rename the last partial migration in database to the name of the merged migration and delete the other partial migrations

This needs to be done before the update process, which is a pity, but the number of instalations is not that high, so it's doable.

Alternative approach would be to run a script that does it before the migrations are applied, but I don't like to have one-time obscure hacks as part of the project